# How to parameterize api url in powerapps?

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

In power apps, I'm using custom connector. 
If the input is Fuji Apples or Indian mango, the URL becomes
http://Api.supermarket.com/ (http://Api.supermarket.com/)v1/groceries/fruits/fresh/ apple?userkey=123
Or
/Fruits/fresh/mango?

Or 
If the input is washington apple it becomes
/Fruits/ fresh/ mango?
Or if the input is organic potato it becomes
/vegetables/fresh/potato?
Like this based on input two parts in the url are changing. 
How to give input in import sample request dialog box to meet this need…

Right now, user_key is the parameter that would be used as input. Could you please help…
?

Answer (score 0):

Its challenging to decipher what you're asking for, but I think you're looking for a way to pass parameters within the URL to the API call. This is known as path templating.

**Here is how I accomplish this:**

- You will need [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) for this solution (its free)
- In Postman, create a new Request with URL as follows: `http://api.supermarket.com/v1/:groceries/:fruits/apple?userkey=123`

  - Notice the `:` in front of the areas you wish to templatize
  - These will become variables in the Custom Connector
- Export the Postman Collection as `V1 deprecated`
- Import the Postman Collection into PowerApps as a **new** Custom Connector

You'll now be able to pass parameters to the URL in your PowerApps Custom Connector

Cheers!

[Original solution in PowerApps Community](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Custom-Connectors-how-to-pass-parameters/m-p/356530/highlight/true#M102146)